# Please run with 'pythonw', not 'python' -- cannot make plots in python/ipython from cmd line OSX

Tags: macos, installation, virtualenv, enthought, pythonw

I am completely new to python installation and took the route of using the Enthought Canopy distribution of python 2.7.6 for my OSX 10.6 32-bit

I have the notebook working smoothly along with everything inside of the Canopy interface. However, when I run the same script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import pylab
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

in the command line using '`python ~/Docs/test.py`' or '`ipython ~/Docs/test.py`' I get this error:

```
This program needs access to the screen.
Please run with 'pythonw', not 'python', and only when you are logged
in on the main display of your Mac.
```

which I have searched and find some information [here](http://wiki.wxpython.org/wxPythonVirtualenvOnMac) but since it is functioning in Canopy, pythonw, and notebook, I'm not sure this is the answer to my problem. I just don't see why there would be a different backdoor for python and ipython in the command line. Did I say that right?

Also, would installation using homebrew remedy this problem? I like to be able to use the canopy gui, but it seems like once canopy is installed it changes everything. I ask this because I am getting a new mac shortly and have found considerably more streamlined installation procedures [here](http://www.lowindata.com/2013/installing-scientific-python-on-mac-os-x/) and a virtual environment set-up guide [here](http://cs.dartmouth.edu/~nfoti/blog/posts/2012/07/17/setting-up-python-in-virtualenv-for-data-analysis-on-osx/). But I still want to have the Canopy GUI as an option.

Thankyou in advance.

Edit:

Alright, ipython notebook gives the same error. I closed and restarted it. It was because I invoked `%pylab inline`. I was not clearing the memory after each run.

Comment: I have a similar problem. When I try to import matplotlib in python an error message tells me to use pythonw. This does fix the problem. However, I want to use python from within other applications, such as building directly from sublime text. I do not want to have to change all command calls to use pythonw if I can avoid this. 

My question is this: how can I install python in such a way on OSX such that it will run matplotlib without pythonw. I had this working a while ago on my machine, but I don't know how to get back to this. Cheers - this problem has been troubling me for hours.

Comment: Did you find a solution @Chogg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
ipython --pylab=osx
```

and

```
ipython notebook --pylab=osx
```

as a workaround to get the graphics for these two. Documentation here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22861925-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks-Python-Canopy

Anyone know how to set this to default?

Though using `%pylab inline` is what you want if you want to keep all of your graphics within the ipython notebook. Choosing osx will open windows outside of the browser. So you can write `ipython notebook --pylab=inline` to invoke this.